# Show that $\int_{a}^{b} |f|^2\le\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}\int_{a}^{b} |f'|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f$ be an differentiable function. Show that $$\int_{a}^{b} |f|^2\le\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}\int_{a}^{b} |f'|^2$$

Can you give me any Hint please (why not, $(b-a)^2$, where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from ?)

Comment: That's not true as written, consider $f \equiv 1$. You need something like $f(a) = 0$ or so.

Comment: yes, sorry for that. it was asked on exam, i couldn't remember the full question, but i saw a similar (almost equal) question here last week. I don't know how to find it.

Comment: If you assume $f(a) = 0$, write $f$ as the integral of the derivative, and apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the comment by @Daniel Fischer, we must assume $f(a)=0$. 
\begin{equation}
|f(x)|=|\int_a^xf'(t)dt|\leq\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt\leq\sqrt{x-a}\sqrt{\int_a^x|f'(t)|^2dt}\leq\sqrt{x-a}\sqrt{\int_a^b|f'(t)|^2dt}
\end{equation}
where $x\in[a,b]$. Then
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx\leq\int_a^b(x-a)\int_a^b|f'(t)|^2dtdx=\int_a^b|f'(t)|^2dt\int_a^b(x-a)dx\\
=\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}\int_a^b|f'(t)|^2dt
\end{equation}

Comment: but you have some typos. it must be $|f'(t)|$ not $|f(t)|$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edit it. Maybe I am a little tired...

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.

Take $f(x)=1$, then the right-hand side is equal to $b-a$, while the right-hand side vanishes.

This inequality could perhaps hold if you further assume that $f$ vanishes at $a$ or $b$ or both or it has average zero.