# Integral bound, inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, inequality

Question:

Given $a<b$. Show that there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
\int_a^b|f(x)|^2\,dx \leq C\int_a^b |f'(x)|^2\,dx
$$
for all function $f\in H^1([a,b])$ with $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$.

My trial:

It looks like a Cauchy-Schwarz question to me, but I did not manage to prove the inequality using the CS inequality. I'm not quite sure where to use the condition $\int_a^b f(x
)\,dx = 0$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271879). See also [on Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_a%5Eb%7Cf(x)%7C%5E2%5C%2Cdx%20%5Cleq%20C%5Cint_a%5Eb%20%7Cf%27(x)%7C%5E2%5C%2Cdx%24&p=1).

Comment: $f$ is zero somewhere in the interval, and then you can proceed as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/679667/42969

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR ! The given condition was stronger than the required one, now I see where I can use the condition. Thank you very much!